# How to covert date variable as Month Name :

Tags: php, mysql

i try to insert date **($dateTime)** variable as month name **(January....)**

```
 $dateTime = $req->date;
   $arr = explode(" ",$dateTime);
    $date = $arr[0];

$openPunch->in_time = $dateTime;
$ok = $openPunch->Save();
```

when i try this code it will saving in my sql database date as this format **('2015-12-09 11:51:28
')** but i want save only Month name **('December')** ????? how can i achive my target ???

Comment: `date('F', strtotime($date_variable))`

Comment: @Prudential.. check my answer and try it hope it will be helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL  `DATE_FORMAT`

```
DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-09 11:51:28','%M')
```

for insert

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1)
VALUES (DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-09 11:51:28','%M'))
```

Comment: 2015-12-09 11:51:28 this is sample date i have mention what i want is i want covert this **$dateTime** variable i think but i tried your way it wont work

Comment: use **DATE_FORMAT(' $dateTime','%M')** @PrudentialDeveloper

Answer (score 1):

**This is same as per your need**

**you can set $dateTime = $req->date;**

```
<?php
 $dateTime=date('Y-m-d h:m:i');
 $arr = explode(" ",$dateTime);
 $date=explode("-",$arr[0]);
 $monthNum = $date[1];
 echo $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you its our duty to guide and give accurate answer!

Answer (score 0):

IF OrderDate is look like   `2014-12-11 13:23:44.657` in you SQL database

**SQL QUERY**

```
$monthNum =   SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM OrderDate) AS OrderMonth ;
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
echo $monthName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not save month only text on a column which has a [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) format.

But you can still fetch the data in a text format of a month either by your query or PHP.

Using `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'%M') AS year_text FROM table
```

Using `php`:

```
$dateTime = date("F", strtotime($dateTime));
```

But if you really want to store the month in text format on your MySQL database, you can use string type of column like [`char`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) or [`varchar`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html).